# Creating React components without rendering them

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create some components that need to communicate their loading states to the parent component.

Here's an example:

```
const Parent = () => {
    // Loading
    const [hasFirstFinishedLoading, setHasFirstFinishedLoading] = React.useState(false);
    const [hasSecondFinishedLoading, setHasSecondFinishedLoading] = React.useState(false);

    const children = (
        <>
            <First 
                onFinishedLoading={() => setHasFirstFinishedLoading(true)}
            />
            <Second 
                onFinishedLoading={() => setHasSecondFinishedLoading(true)}
            />
        </>
    );

    if (hasFirstFinishedLoading && hasSecondFinishedLoading) {
        return <>{children}</>
    }
    
    return <LoadingComponent />
}
```

Essentially, the idea is that I render a Loading component while the children components are loading (i.e making some network requests). However, this doesn't work because the children component are not mounted, and so they don't start their loading process.

Is there a way to mount the children components so they can load?

Some approaches I've already considered:

1. Create a top level context that handles loading (i.e network requests) and let that control rendering. I can just render the children components once the context has finished its network requests.
2. Render the children components, but set `display:none`.

Are there any other approaches?

Comment: You can have the children component conditionally render content based on a condition. See https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

Your approaches sound reasonable. As soon as React 18 is released, however, `Suspense` will be officially available. It is built for exactly this use case, but currently only experimental support is available. Check out the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) for more info.